# Can you say anything if you see cheating at another board?

Tags: cheating

Let's say you see that player A on the board next to yours violates a rule such as touch-move or changes the move after releasing the piece, but their opponent, player B, doesn't notice. Can you say anything to player B, and if so, could B make a claim based on third-party testimony for a violation B didn't even see?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not address player B directly, it is forbidden to talk to him about his game (it is actually forbidden to talk to him at all, but the spirit of the law is to prevent conversations about the game).

However, you can (and should) tell the arbiter about what you have seen, and the arbiter will decide on the appropriate action.

Comment: Good point about not talking to B. But could/should the arbiter do anything without the interested player (B) making a claim?

Comment: @itub That sounds like it deserves its own question.

Comment: Would the arbiter notice himself cheating, he would intervene without needing the opponent's request. In the case he has no other information that what you told him, his reaction might depend on a lot of other factors, but at the least he'll be very careful about A's behavior afterwards.